# Touch event initial coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas, touch

I was searching for an answer but couldn't find any. My problem is:

I need an object to appear on canvas when I touch it and to disappear when I cancel the touch event (lift my finger). 
However, I need the object to have the initial coordinates of the original touch position, meaning I don't want it to move with my finger.

```
var can = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var WIDTH = can.width;
var HEIGHT = can.height;
var canX;
var canY;
var mouseIsDown = 0; 
var requestAnimFrame =  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;


var image = new Image();
image.src = '1.png';


function init(){
    can.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
    can.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseXY, false);

    document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
    loop();
}


function mouseUp() {
    mouseIsDown = 0;
    mouseXY();
}


function mouseDown() {
    mouseIsDown = 1;
    mouseXY();
}


function mouseXY(e) {
    if (!e)
        e = event;
    canX = e.pageX - can.offsetLeft;
    canY = e.pageY - can.offsetTop;
}


function loop(){
    if(mouseIsDown===1){
        draw();
    } else 
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    requestAnimFrame(loop);
}


function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,40,40,canX-20,canY-20,40,40);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Read on `touchstart` event: http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/.

Comment: I need when I touch the screen 2 elements to appear, 1 that will follow my finger (made that one) and the other that will stay in place (that I touched the screen) until I lift it (my finger and cancel touch event). I guess it has something to do with identifier

Comment: Novak, show us the code.

Comment: Here's the code with mouse event (I need that too), HTML has only canvas with id= "can" and w:320 and h:480 (irrelevant for my point). Here's the thing, I don't want that image to follow my pointer, I just want it to appear when I click (or touch) stay in that position (where I clicked/touched) as long as I have mousedown or touchstart running and I want it to disappear when I cancel it. That's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the initial mouse/touch position in a separate pair of variables.

```
var initialCanX, initialCanY;

function mouseDown(e) {
    mouseIsDown = 1;

    initialCanX = e.pageX - can.offsetLeft;
    initialCanY = e.pageY - can.offsetTop;

    mouseXY(e);
}
```

And then, in the drawing function, use these coordinates to draw the second image.

```
function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.drawImage(image, canX, canY); // the moving image
    ctx.drawImage(image2, initialCanX, initialCanY); // the static image
}
```